# How determine that request came from outer server in java servlet?

Tags: java, servlets, refer

How determine that request which is sent to servlet is sent from outer server? Is it safe to use `getServerName`:

```
public class SaveVisitorServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String referer = req.getHeader("Referer");
        if (!"www.myownhost.com".equals(req.getServerName())) {
            saveRefereToDb(referer);
        }
    }
}
```

So the meaning is if request does not come from server where servlet is deployed nothing is saved to database.

Can `req.getServerName()` be used here?

Comment: I am confused here, how can one decide if request comes from a server then its safe? Hacker can manipulate the request to pretend to be a server .

Comment: I guess you misunderstand the meaning of this code snippet. Looks like all referrers that do not use the address `www.myownhost.com` to access the server are stored. Maybe there are other (outdated) domain names for the same server and referres of the old names should be identified.